# Free Fall time in General Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, time, free-fall

Suppose you are working with the Schwarzschild metric in GR.
$$
-c^2 \mathrm d \tau ^2 = -c^2 \left (1 - \frac{2 G M}{c^2 r} \right) \mathrm d t^2 +  \left (1 - \frac{2 G M}{c^2 r} \right)^{-1} \mathrm d r^2 + r^2 \; \mathrm d \Omega ^2 
$$

Analyzing the symmetries, our free fall only depends on $r(\tau)$, so we can omit everything else in the metric.
$$
-c^2 \mathrm d \tau ^2 = -c^2 \left (1 - \frac{2 G M}{c^2 r} \right) \mathrm d t^2 +  \left (1 - \frac{2 G M}{c^2 r} \right)^{-1}\mathrm d r^2 
$$
Rearrange and arrive to:

$$
-c^2 = -c^2 \left (  1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r} \right) \gamma \left(\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d \tau}\right)^2 +  \left (  1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r} \right) ^{-1}\left (\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d \tau} \right)^2 \\
\gamma(v) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

Is this equation correct? How could I solve it?

---

##### Newtonian Limit:

$$
\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d \tau} \ll c \rightarrow  \frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d \tau} \approx \frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t} \\
m \frac{\mathrm d r^2}{\mathrm d t^2} = -G\frac{ mM}{r^2} \rightarrow m \frac{\mathrm d r^2}{\mathrm d t^2} \frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t} = -G\frac{ mM}{r^2} \frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t}
$$
Now if I integrate:
$$
m\int_{v_0}^{v(t)} {v \frac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm d t} } \; \mathrm d t = -GMm \int_{r_0}^{r(t)} {\frac{v}{r^2}\; \mathrm d t} \\
\frac{1}{2}m \left( v(t)^2 - v_0^2 \right) = GMm \left[\frac{1}{r(t)} - \frac{1}{r_0}\right] \\
v(t) = \sqrt{v_0^2 +2GM \left [\frac{1}{r(t)} - \frac{1}{r_0} \right]}
$$
How would you arrive to this limit through GR?

Comment: Why are you dropping the dt term?

Comment: Thats what I was asking. It is necessary? I suppose that yes, no?

Comment: Yes, you need the $dt$ term. Note that $\gamma = \frac{dt}{d\tau}$ isn't constant.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://hepweb.ucsd.edu/ph110b/110b_notes/node80.html